# How to bend a plane I modified?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms, geometry

I've used a plane to model this:

[image]

[image]

I want it to bend but when I add a "Simple Deform" modifier and I select "bend", here's what I get:

[image]

As you can see only some of the faces are going to be bend.

**Q:** What can I do to bend the geometry as a whole?

Comment: If it's subdivided use the curve modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to put it on the Z axis, apply then rotate it. Found the answer on [this video (at 3:45)](https://youtu.be/bMYccraiLQU?t=221) while searching for a solution.